# How can I remove default zoom in/out [+/-] buttons from openlayers to keep the navigation bar on?

Tags: openlayers-2, toolbar, navigation, default

I want to remove the default zoom +/- buttons from openlayers.

Here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, ia_wms;
    function init(){
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {zoomDuration: 1,projection: 'EPSG:3857'
***/*controls: [
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ]*/***
    });
    var sr_all = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("EOL","http://192.168.0.233/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/mstest/plant.map",{'layers':"map_outline",'transparent':true,'format':'image/png'}
           ,{
            isBaseLayer: false,opacity: 100
            },
            {singleTile: true, ratio: 1}
            );
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Streets", // the default
    { numZoomLevels: 25,visibility: false}
    ,{
        isBaseLayer: true
    }
    );      
    map.addLayers([sr_all,gmap]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());

    map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(69.728426,22.311238,69.774227,22.356185));
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(69.754227,22.332185).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 14);
    }
</script>
```

when I added,
        controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
        ]
to the map = new OpenLayers.Map, to remove default zoom +/- buttons, the map is not loading.
Please see the image also.

[image: Both the navigation buttons exist. :(]
Both the navigation buttons exist. :(

**I want to remove the small- 2 button- one.**
I changed the code like this:

```
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {zoomDuration: 1,projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    controls: []
    });
```

and added

```
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
```

But, the map is not loading. Do not know any syntax error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to remove the big one (blue one?) or the small one behind it? if the big one is the issue, try commenting:

> map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());

and you should get only one control like [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/osm.html):

```
var map, layer;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(
                new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    map.getProjectionObject()
                ), 12
            );    
        }
```

If the 2nd is the issue, follow [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/pan-zoom-panels.html) and adapt it as you wish:

```
var map;
    var lon = 5;
    var lat = 40;
    var zoom = 5;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanPanel(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel()
            ]
        });

        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: 'basic'}
        );
        map.addLayers([wms]);

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    }
```

Comment: Both links are dead :/

Answer (score 8):

You should initialize the map with no controls. You can do this passing an empty array to the controls like this:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', 
    {zoomDuration: 1,projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    controls: []});
```

You should then add only those controls that you require, like this:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution());
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 var options = {
        controls: [
         //   new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom({
                zoomInId: "bplus",
                zoomOutId: "bminus"
            }),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(
        { div: document.getElementById("coordinates") })
        ],
        transitionEffect: 'none',

    };
```

you can add custom zoom like that

Answer (score 0):

Use it , It works well no zoom buttons and navigation still works!

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', 
    {...
     controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

below line hide default zoom in/out [+/-]
`buttonsmMapView.getZoomController().setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER);`